# how to get data from a ftp server/client before it sends it data to TCP socket

Tags: c++

In my program I need to get data from FTP server/client before it sends its data to TCP socket, after getting data I have to attach 8-bytes of data(that will be added in start of the payload) to it and then reverting it back to tcp socket. Is it even possible? I searched on net with no luck

Comment: cURL library might be helpful to get the file from the FTP server. Once you receive a data add your header and send it over to socket.

Comment: can you provide me some good reading material on cURL?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/

Comment: I am following http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf for compiling libcurl but there is no curllib.dsw file in lib directory.. I have downloaded many versions but found no file as curllib.dsw in any version. i am using window7 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pragnesh suggested, use cURL library. However using cURL means it will both create the packets and send it over the socket. You may try the following two approaches

1. The first option is to modify the cURL code itself so that before the packets are written onto socket they are modified. But this will involve gaining a good understanding of the FTP library and recompiling the whole code. This is possible but is not a neat approach.
2. The second approach works as follows
   a. Allow the library ( cURL or any other library ) to create protocol packets and write it onto socket. However when you pass the FTP server IP to the library pass a fake IP ( this is a temporary IP and will be replaced later ) e.g. 10.1.1.5.

   b. Create a virtual device ( TUN device that is part of standard linux distribution ) and have the FTP protocol packets written to the virtual device at the IP layer. For this add a new route table entry which says that for the packets having destination IP as your fake IP ( 10.1.1.5 in this case ) the destination device should be your TUN device. So every time a FTP protocol packet reaches the IP layer with destination IP as 10.1.1.5, it will be written to the virtual device instead to being sent out of the machine.

   c. In your application listen on the virtual device using the read() command. All the packets that are written onto the virtual device are received at the application. The received packet is a "FTP over TCP over IP" packet. That means it will have the FTP protocol packet, the TCP header and the IP header.

   d. Now you can do pretty much anything with this packet that you want. In your case just get the right offset in the buffer ( the size of IP and TCP header is fixed ) and add your data. Once you have modified the packet, you will have to change two IP addresses. The source IP address in this IP packet is the virtual device IP address not your eth0 address. So replace this source IP with your eth0 address. The destination IP address in the pakcet is the fake IP. Again replace this address with the correct FTP server IP.

   e. Once done recalculate the IP and TCP header checksums. ( These are standard algorithms can be easily found). After this the last thing is to write the packet again on the virtual device using write () command. Once you do that the packet will be injected on the IP layer and this time will go out of the machine. You will have to set the IP forwarding flag and disable the rp-filter settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response and suggestion.
what I want to do is to take data from any network application(by now its FTP server), once i got data from my favorite port, I want to attach my own data to it and then send it to a client on some other system.
one thing that is not clear yet because i am a newbie and i have a little knowledge regarding networking, is that once i get data from FTP, how can i restrict it to not sending data further to TCP socket so that i can attach my own data and then send it to TCP socket/Client socket through my own application. thnks in advance